# STRANGE ERROR! Unable to move Revolute Joints in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-controllers, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running : 1. ROS Indigo 2. Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

I'm simulating a 6DOF robotic arm using ros_control and using gazebo_ros_control plugins. I'm using Joint Position Controllers.

I have set up the .yaml file containing the type of controllers. I have also added all the transmission and gazebo_ros_control tags in my URDF file.

Everything launches without any error. When I try to publish messages on /robot_arm/joint1_position_controller/command topic I'm unable to move the revolute joints. Interestingly I have two continuous joints among my 6DOF which move.

Also these movements are abrupt and not in a smooth manner. Whereas I've tried tutorials where the arm follows a smoother motion using Joint Position Controllers.

How should I get my revolute joints to move? Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236255/strange-error!-unable-to-move-revolute-joints-in-gazebo/) by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-06-07**:
Are you perhaps using a Jaco or Mico arm? I had the same issue and just changed them to continuous joints.

**Comment by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on 2016-06-14**:
Thanks Laurens! Issue sorted out!

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-09-05**:
hello,I also encounter this problem with revolute joints. Is it was the limit seting problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue Solved.

Making the joints continuous works.

But the real problem was that the effort and velocity limits of the revolute joints in my URDF description were set to zero.

---

Originally posted by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) with karma: 99 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2